# Please help me understand what I need to do with "Change needs review" notification in Documentation

Tags: support, notifications, documentation

I just got 2 notifications related to changes that were made in the Documentation section:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/8131?draftId=8465

  This change is related to an example in "AngularJS, Controllers Overview", but I didn't posted the original example - The edit itself looks fine, so should I approve it (Or maybe the OP should do it in the first place?)
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/8081?draftId=8357

  The above is for "AngularJS, Hello World" section - But there is no actual edit in the content, only in the Section versions. So why is there an edit request without any actual change in the content itself?

I'm asking this because the Documentations is new, and I'm not completely sure what I need to do with them, and future notifications like the above.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, now I start getting them notifications every few minutes - So it's probably for every change for every section I ever contribute to?

Comment: The first one: documentation is a collaborative effort. If you think it improves the topic approve it. If it doesn't, don't. Not sure - ignore. The second: that is an edit to the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just remembered that I was the notification settings I set to **Immediately**.

This is still a bit confusing, so I'll leave this post because It might help others like me who forgot to check the notification settings.